# How can you retrieve multiple values with momentjs from firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, momentjs

I get all data from firebase and store it on array and from that array i take all posted_at data (time when was something posted). My goal is to retrieve all that data in some sort of time format and problem is that it won't retrieve multiple values. I am using Vuejs.

```
<template>
  <div v-for="data in array">
    {{ time }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      array:[]//example:1577200868199, 1577200868189,...
    }
  },
  computed:{
    time(){
      moment(this.array.posted_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

P.S. I have tried using a for and a while loop but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice case to use [Vue filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

```
<template>
  <div v-for="data in array">
    {{ data | formatTime }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      array: []//example:1577200868199, 1577200868189,...
    }
  },
  filters: {
    formatTime: function (value) {
      return moment(value).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `{{ data | formatTime }}`? (unless you change to `v-for="time in array"`)

Answer (score 0):

With moment you can only parse one item at a time, so you can change your code to loop over your array and parse each item individually. It would look something like this.

```
this.array.forReach(posted_at => {
 moment(posted_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
})
```