# How to get multiple id's from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have an admin area which collects all data from Firebase in an array. My task is to update data and send it to Firebase for specific users (I need to put some comment). Problem is that in `.doc('id of document')`, I don't know how to get the specific ID of document in Firebase. Function works fine if I put in an ID of a specific document (e.g. `"2jzm4AcWTVNIlT9ESH7V"`). `doc.data()` returns all the data from Firebase and each ID is stored in the object together with the data.

```html
<script>
import moment from 'moment'
export default{
  // ...
  mounted(){
    db.collection("form").where("posted_at", ">=", 1)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
          console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          this.array.push(Object.assign({}, doc.data(), {id: doc.id}));
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
  },
  methods:{
    comment(){
      let id=this.array.id;
      db.collection("form")
        .doc(id)
        .update({
          comment: this.comment1 //data(){return{comment1:''}}
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

P.S. i get this error for function:

```
FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined
```

Comment: This question has been [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59507390).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `let id=this.array.id;` is trying to get the `id` property of the array itself, not the ID of an entry in the array.

Based on the [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1DwGBeS-KU) you are following, when you attach your `comment()` method in the `v-for` loop, you should pass the array entry it relates to in as a parameter. When this method is invoked, it should set the ID that is being edited, load the existing comment (if it exists) and open the modal dialog to edit the comment.

```js
<script>
export default{
  //...
  methods: {
    editComment(userDetails) {
      this.textComment = userDetails.comment || ''; // load current comment
      this.activeUserDetailsId = userDetails.id; // set ID being edited
      $('#commentModal').modal('show'); // show modal dialog
    },
    saveComment() {
      let id = this.activeUserDetailsId;
      if (!id) {
        alert('Failed to save comment - invalid state');
        return;
      }
      db.collection("form")
        .doc(this.activeUserDetailsId)
        .update({
          comment: this.textComment
        })
        .then(function() {
          $('#commentModal').modal('hide');
          console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // TODO: Show error to user
          console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

I have edited, proofed and reworked the [code you provided](https://pastebin.com/raw/Rt30eDYC) into [this updated file](https://pastebin.com/raw/N6M26Xgd). It was written free hand so let me know if there are any bugs.

A summary of the changes:

- Renamed variables to make their use clear
- Added `editComment(userDetails)` and `saveComment()` event handlers
- Fixed usage of `formatTime` filter from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59494301/3068190)
- Added basic handling of no results
- Fixed indentation
- Fixed incorrect placement of your modal `div` - shouldn't have been inside `v-for` loop

Comment: The first function will work but i need all users from array not specific one. Second function- nope i need to update document.

Comment: Have a crack at using `Array.prototype.forEach`. If you're still stuck when I log in tomorrow I'll put something together

Comment: @user12603373 What is the purpose of `comment()`? What is `id`? What does your database look like?

Comment: Comment needs to update every document from array and store it on firebase. Id is document id from firebase database. It looks like a bunch of documents consisting of an address, first name, last name, ..

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes this function updates data for all users but my goal is for specific user. If you didn't understand what my goal is take a look at this video (if you have time and will), this is exactly what i need. https://youtu.be/W1DwGBeS-KU

Comment: So i need to update one particular document from several of them

Comment: @user12603373 Linking that tutorial in your original question would have solved this a lot faster. Anyways, I updated the answer and [reworked your code](https://pastebin.com/raw/N6M26Xgd) as described above.

Comment: Yup, it works. Just on your pastebin link you need to put @click="editComment(userDetails)" on button instead in form, becuase it won't recognize id. Tnx for help